# Template function enable if with template only

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Based on the following templated struct, used as pixel accessor.

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct PixelAccessor
{   
    T ch[N];
};

using pxUChar_C1 = PixelAccessor<unsigned char, 1>;
using pxUChar_C3 = PixelAccessor<unsigned char, 3>;
using pxUChar_C4 = PixelAccessor<unsigned char, 4>;

using pxFloat_C1 = PixelAccessor<float, 1>;
using pxFloat_C3 = PixelAccessor<float, 3>;
using pxFloat_C4 = PixelAccessor<float, 4>;

// etc. for all other types (int, short, ushort, ...)
```

I made the following function to work only with uchar and float pixel that are 3 channels.

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, pxUChar_C3>::value || std::is_same<T, pxFloat_C3>::value>::type>
bool function(Image img) {
     // where getData is uchar*, and cast to T** allow 2D accessing
    auto imgPtr = (T**)img->getData();
}
```

Is there a way to do the following, or anything similar ? I would like to enable all 3 channels pixel, what ever there type is ?

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of< PixelAcessor<std::any, 3>,T>::value>::type>
```

I would like to have a C++11 solution, but if there is a need of a newer compiler, Im open to solution and see what I do.

Comment: That won't work, `std::any` not some wild card for template deduction. But you could try to give `PixelAccessor` a simple base type such that all `PixelAccessor<T,N>` *would* be testable with a `is_base_of`. Something like `PixelAccessorBase<N>`, since you want to allow any kind of `PixelAccessor` provided it has some expected value of `N`.

Comment: I know it not working. I wondering how to replace the std::any by something that could do it. I put std::any to show what I kinda trying to do with obvious terms such as "any".

Comment: How does the function use `T`? Or `PixelAcessor` for that matter.

Comment: @Vuwox There is no such wild card place holder. Edit: The inheritance approach is probably the simplest solution to what you're trying to do. You could also try to write your own type trait.

Comment: @StoryTeller The function use T to manipulate the image using the template as a cast over the data array. The data is store in 1D fashion of bytes, that need to be cast based on the template T.

Comment: Just to clarfy - you want to accept any `PixelAccessor<T, 3>`, i.e. it does not matter what `T` is, it's just the `ch` is of a size `3`?

Comment: @StoryTeller I edit the function to show how I use it.

Comment: @Fureeish Exactly... I think your question made my template foolish, since instead of using T, I could use PixelAccessor<T,3> in the code...

Comment: And that's exactly what NathanOliver proposes :> Although, if you really want to use SFINAE, for example for practise, you could introduce a `static` value equal to `N` in your class and `enable_if` in that value being equal to `3`.

Comment: @Fureeish - That's not exactly what Nathan proposes. Nathan's answer is contingent on the function taking a `PixelAccessor<T,3>`, that's not what the OP has. I suspect what the OP means is to simply do `PixelAccessor<T,3>**` in the cast.

Comment: @Vuwox - By the way, if you figured out your own answer to question you can post it. SO is all about answer diversity. Makes for the best posts.

Comment: @StoryTeller Exactly. So at the end I have the following `template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>` and Im using `auto imgPtr = (PixelAccessor<T,3>**)img->getData();`.

Answer (score 5):

To get the function to take any `PixelAccessor` where `N` is `3` then you don't need `enable_if` and SFINAE.  Just using

```
template<typename T>
return_type function_name(PixelAccessor<T, 3> parameter_name)
{
    // stuff
}
```

will give you a function that takes a `PixelAccessor` of any type and has a size of 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom channel extraction meta-function:

```
template<typename> struct GetPixelAccessorChannel
{ static constexpr std::size_t value = 0; }; 

template<typename T, std::size_t N> struct GetPixelAccessorChannel<PixelAccessor<T, N>>
{ static constexpr std::size_t value = N; };
```

Now it's a simple matter of testing the proper condition in the `enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<GetPixelAccessorChannel<T>::value == 3>::type>
bool function();
```

And as an aside, I'd rethink `(T**)img->getData()` in your stead. Needing such a cast looks very fishy to me.

Comment: The code has been made like that by previous dev. Its too avoid handling the row pitch, number of channels, etc, so that the cast enable faster accessing.

Comment: @Vuwox - *Sigh*. Seems like there's always a "previous dev" that writes code like that in every organization.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, the usage of a wildcard such as `std::any` is not possible in template.

But after discussion, the usage of the template like I asked was a bit foolish, since I want to always use the T as a PixelAccessor itself, so it possible to use it differently such as I only template the T for the PixelAccessor itself.

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
bool function(Image img) {

    // Sanity check
    if(img->getNbChannels() != 3) return false;

    // where getData is uchar*, and cast to T** allow 2D accessing
    auto imgPtr = (PixelAccessor<T, 3>**)img->getData();
}
```